# How to use Struts 2 push tag for form input fields?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I have two classes one is Action class `MyAction` and other is POJO class `User`. Inside `MyAction`, i have made getter-setter for `User` class.

Then I have `index.jsp` page for user input. In this, I am using struts 2 `push` tag for the properties stored in `User` class. It looks something like this:

```jsp
<s:form action="go" method="post">
    <s:push value="user">
        <s:textfield name="id" label="usr-id"/>              <!-- user.id    -->
        <s:textfield name="fname" label="first-name"/>       <!-- user.fname -->
    </s:push>
    <s:submit/>
    <s:token/>
</s:form>
```

But I am getting an error. If I remove the push tag and prefix the `User` properties with `user`, then it runs fine. Can any one guide me, where I am wrong and how to use `push` tag for input fields in form.

Comment: Your help is here: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-push-tag-example/

Comment: Thank You @Imran . So according to mkyong, we have to first make `bean` and then refer that bean to `push` value. Your (mkyong's) solution is great, but isn't there a direct way? Suppose, I have a long OGNL expr like `user.address.city`... how to achieve this. I know I sound like mad, but could you help me in long chain of OGNL in push tag.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you @Imran, But thank you. I got my confusion cleared away. Have a nice day!

Comment: Why you are using a `<s:push>` tag at all?

Comment: Isn't it worthy? I mean, if we have so many properties for same object, then isn't it good practice to push that object on top of value stack...instead of suffixing every time that object with it's  properties. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not really. One of the points is: you can easily miss that some tags are used inside push tag.

Answer (score 1):

No matter if you use `<s:push>`, `<s:set/>`, `<s:iterator>` with its `var` or `IteratorStatus` attributes... :

- to ***show*** a value, any way is a good way;
- to ***send*** a value, the *only* way is specifying the full "path" in the `name` attribute.

For example, you can use the pushed object in the value attribute, but to make it work when submitting, you still need to put the `user` in name attribute:

```xml
<s:push value="user">
    <s:textfield name="user.id" value="id"      />       <!-- user.id    -->
    <s:textfield name="user.fname" value="fname"/>       <!-- user.fname -->
</s:push>
```

This makes the use of `<s:push>` in your case totally useless.

But in an use-case where source and destination differs, eg. you read `user.fname` from ActionSource, and send its value to ActionDestination in a `selectedFname` String, the jsp would be

```xml
<s:push value="user">
    <s:textfield name="selectedId"    value="id"   />       <!-- user.id    -->
    <s:textfield name="selectedFname" value="fname"/>       <!-- user.fname -->
</s:push>
```

So it would have done *"something usefull"*.

But basing on my experience, you won't pretty much never use push. If you need it, your data structure is probably too complex.

Comment: Thanks @Andrea. I want to ask, can I use `push` tag with a `bean` tag. Like first creating a bean for `User` class with `var` attribute and then referring it to `push` value. Here is a link from where I got this logic: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-push-tag-example/

Comment: I pretty much never use the <s:bean> (and, before you ask, the <s:action>) tag too. That's not a bad practice itself, I just consider it an old way of *thinking* the way one codes. I've used them years ago, I've no need anymore.

Comment: @JSK I see the future: [*and, before you ask, the <s:action>*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26291223/1654265) :D P.S: if you've found the answer useful, please consider up-voting it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like ok, but to send values from textfields you need to push the `user` object to the stack again. Better do it with some interceptor before the `params` interceptor populates the action. The same thing is doing [`modelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/model-driven-interceptor.html).

> The Model-Driven interceptor watches for `ModelDriven` actions and adds the action's model on `top` of the value stack.
>
> **Note:** The `ModelDrivenInterceptor` must come before the both `StaticParametersInterceptor` and `ParametersInterceptor` if you want the parameters to be applied to the model.
>
> **Note:** The `ModelDrivenInterceptor` will only push the model into the stack when the model is not `null`, else it will be ignored.

You can use model driven approach it's pushing a model for the view and for the controller. The last is missing from your code.

[The example of using `ModelDriven` approach](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-modeldriven-example/).

Comment: Thank you @roman for clearing my doubts to some extent. Yes, I have used `ModelDrivenInterceptor`. Here I was just trying to understand how `push` tags works. For receiving data via `properties` tag inside `push` there was no problem. But Error came when I tried to send the data using same `push` tag. So, according to you what I understood is: `param` interceptor is firing here when I press submit button and it (param) is reinitializing the value stack again. Thus ignoring the pushed object. Am I wrong or right?

Comment: The pushed object pops from the stack at the end of the tag leaving you unhappy. Also submitting a form required a new request to the server, and new action context and value stack.

Comment: Oh yeah, it pops out from stack on `</s:push>`. With your magical comments, there is now no doubt and I am now happy. Thank you. :) Also, can you just explain me little further, that why does `push` tag mysteriously starts working when combined with `s:bean` tag. Like here http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-push-tag-example/

Comment: What do you mean *starts working*? It's working in the example linked, not in your case. the `bean` tag creates a bean and make a reference variable in the value stack context. Then you can use `#` reference to access bean's properties. After pushing this bean on the stack properties accessed directly. And this example only works on the same view without any textfields and submitting them to the action.

Comment: so sorry for wasting your time. I mistakenly looked that link for sending data from form input fields. I will stick with your guidance i.e I will continue to use `ModelDriven` in such scenarios. And will only use `push` tag for receiving back properties.

Comment: The `push` tag works with the value stack on the view layer, where it's applicable in the current action context and it doesn't work in another action request, because it runs in another context. If you want the model persist between requests use `scopedModelDriven` interceptor.

Comment: @JSK: Don't use modeldriven. Things just work w/o modeldriven and push tag and bean tag. Keep it simple.

Comment: @AleksandrM This is *good* approach - don't use something if you don't know how to use it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Push is not a ui tag. Push is used for put objects into top of value stack. If your object is not in top of stack you get your values by using `object.attributname`. If your object is in the value stack, you can access it directly `attributename`.