# How to use ignoreContextParams attribute in s:action tag for struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

In Struts 2, there is a `<s:action>` tag, which has a boolean `ignoreContextParams` attribute. It's used like this:

```
<s:action name="goTo_read" executeResult="true" **ignoreContexParams="true"**/>
```

in docs, it has been written for `ignoreContextParams` that when it is set to `true`, then the **request parameters** are not included when the action is invoked.

So in order to check/test that thing I make my parameters with `<result></result>` tags in `struts.xml` like below:

```
<action name="goTo_read" class="abc.CompoundAction" method="doRead">
<result name="sendToRead">/one.jsp?fruit=banana</result>
</action>
```

`ignoreContextParams` being already set to `true` in `<s:action>` tag does not make any change, i.e. I am able to get parameter `fruit` from `one.jsp`; which according to docs should not be allowed.
Can anyone guide me how/where to use `ignoreContextParams`. Can any one tell me why am I getting parameter values even when I set `ignoreContextParams` to `true`.

Comment: Have you read the docs about this tag? What is unclear for you?

Comment: Did you use <s:action> tag? Do you have any problems with it, if yes then clarify the question what did you try and where you stuck. Because the question as it's currently written is not clear what are you asking.

Comment: @RomanC @AleksandrM, Sir, `<s:action>` tag has a boolean attribute `ignoreContextParams` like `<s:action name="goTo_read" executeResult="true" ignoreContextParams="true"/>` . Its written in docs for `ignoreContextParams` when set to true, the request parameters are not included when the action is invoked. So, in order to check/test that I added a parameter in `result` inside `struts.xml`; like `<result name="success">/welcome.jsp?fruit=banana</result>`. continue in next comment...

Comment: `ignoreContextParams` being already set to `true` did not make any change. i.e I am able to get and view parameters, which should not according to docs.

Comment: @JSK Use an edit link below the question and add details with code, how did you check that?

Comment: @RomanC I have edited my question. I hope now it is more clear.

Comment: It is for ignoring action context parameters not all parameters.

Comment: @AleksandrM , could you please give me advice on how to set `action context parameters` , using which I can test the above question.

Comment: Put that `?fruit=banana` into your browser url with action which points to jsp where `<s:action>` is.

Comment: @AleksandrM no change. I did this: **http://localhost:5353/struts...new...struts2Tags_ActionTag/one.action?fruit=banana** `ignoreContextParams`was set to true, yet I received banana on one.jsp

Comment: If you are calling this where is `<s:action>` tag? You need to do: Call `one.action?fruit=banana` that shows `one.jsp` in which put `<s:action>` tag calling some different action in which you will receive fruit or not.